# Get ASCII-6 encoding in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, ascii

I'm using a legacy binary message format that requires a character sequence in ASCII-6 (6 bit ascii) encoding. I couldn't find a definition for ASCII-6 but they define the character mappings in their spec starting with A=0x01, B=0x02, etc.

I'm wondering if there is an existing characterset in java for ASCII-6. If not can you create or define your own characterset somehow? If not is there a better solution than to create a map of characters to ascii-6 encoded values?

Comment: If each character takes 6-bit, how are they packed into 8-bit bytes? Do you get 4 characters for every 3 bytes? Writing your own converter is likely to be simpler than developing a CharSet.

Comment: No, they do expect every character to be packed into 6 bits, not 8 bits. I'm going to be using something like http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/BinaryOut.java.html to deal with writing things out on non byte boundaries. But I have to deal with converting every character to their ascii-6 encoding first, then write out the 6 least significant bits and I thought using a predefined or my own charset here would be quickest.

Comment: All data stream are basically 8-bits per byte.  There is no other option.  You can make it look like there is 6-bits or 16-bit but you have to know how you intend to map this to an 8-bit stream. I suggest you read the documentation for a CharSet before you decide if its the simplest. ;)

Comment: Yea, I was thinking that an existing charset or writing one would just be the simplest way (fewest lines) to map utf-8/utf-16 chars to their ascii-6 encodings. Then I'd have to use one of those binary output streams to write out the 6 least significant bits of each byte/char.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if any 6-bit encoding exists where A is `0x01`, B is `0x02` etc. but characters in most six-bit encodings are interchangeable with ASCII-7 characters through integer arithmetic. For example, characters in the [SIXBIT DEC encoding](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/telecom/codes/sixbit.html) can be changed to ASCII-7 characters by addition of 32 (base 10), and vice versa, as the SIXBIT encoding scheme carries only the printable characters in the ASCII-7 character set.

Implementing support for such an transformation involving `Byte`s and `Character`s will require you to write a [`Charset`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) and register it using a [`CharsetProvider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html). The tricky part is in mapping sequences of 6-bits to Unicode characters, as the `Byte` is the most fundamental unit that charset [`Encoders`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) and [`Decoders`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) operate on. On the other hand, if you are operating against 6-bit encoded characters that each require 8-bit wide characters, then the said arithmetic operation becomes easy, otherwise you will need to track whether the encoder/decoder is in an invalid state.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own character encoding by writing a class that extends `CharsetProvider` and making it available to your application. For instance, [JCharset](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/) does this for some lesser-used encodings. As fas as I can see even they don't support old ASCII variants, but you can see how it's done by studying that implementation. It's not particularly hard, just somewhat tedious.

Comment: Are you able to download JCharset? For me the download link links back to http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/, which is where I started

Comment: Yes, but you need to accept the licence terms by clicking the checkbox first (possibly Javascript must also be enabled).

Comment: Oh, my corporate proxy was blocking the javascript file. Thanks, I'll take a look.